# How old is Voldemort really?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Voldemort is, what, 72 years old when he died, right? But why in here:

> Of all the unusual things about Harry, this scar was the most extraordinary of all. It was not, as the Dursleys had pretended for ten years, a souvenir of the car crash that had killed Harry’s parents, because Lily and James Potter had not died in a car crash. **They had been murdered, murdered by the most feared Dark wizard for a hundred years, Lord Voldemort.**

*Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 1, Owl Post*

**A hundred years.**
Is it just a hyperbole or something?

Comment: this is an English question not a Harry Potter question

Comment: No, I misunderstood it. I thought it contradicts everything about Voldemort's age. That's why I'm asking here.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Voldemort was **71** years old when he died: [Born 31 December 1926, died 2 May 1998](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/lord-voldemort).

---

The quote

> Most feared dark wizard for a hundred years

means, "*in the last 100 years, the dark wizard who was **most feared** was Voldemort.*"

In other words, in the previous 100 years there weren't any *other* dark wizards who were *more feared* than Voldemort.

Comment: My mind is clear now, and at peace too, thanks to you!